How do i make a predetermined parameter for a struct inside a constructor
Whenever i try to run my program, it gives me an error saying that i'm missing an argument for the eight parameter in my constructor
Here is the struct
Here is the struct
struct maximos {
    size_t lengthTitulo;
    size_t lengthAutor;
    size_t lengthIdioma;
    size_t lengthGenero;
    void CreacionVariables();
    
};

Here is the constructor
Libro(const std::string = "", const std::string = "", const std::string = "", int = 0, int = 0, const std::string = "", int = 0, maximos&);

i've tried writing "maximos& obj", but it doesn't work.
other than that i don't know what to do.

Libro is not a constructor for maximos

I'm not using Libro as a constructor for maximos, i want to know how to put maximos inside the constructor as a predetermined parameter

Always post verbatim error messages. I am pretty sure if you read the error to the end then it contains an answer. Non default parameters are not allowed after the parameters with the default arguments. If it was allowed, how would compiler know which arguments are to wich parameters.

I know, but i don't know how to make it a default argument

You supposed to post a [mre] so we know what you want to implement. Now your question looks like the XY-problem - your are solving X but asking how to solve Y.

If you want to pass a default argument to the last parameter then declare it const:
Libro(const std::string = "", const std::string = "", const std::string = "", int = 0, int = 0, const std::string = "", int = 0, const maximos& = {});

You cannot make it non const because a non const reference can't bind rvalue, which is a default argument because it does not have a name.
If you strictly should pass a non const default argument, then overloaded functions/constructors are your friends.
Libro(const std::string, const std::string, const std::string, int, int, const std::string, int, maximos&);

Libro(const std::string a = "", const std::string b = "", const std::string c = "", int d = 0, int e = 0, const std::string f = "", int g = 0) {
  maximos deafault_maximos;
  Libro(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, deafault_maximos);
}


Thanks, that is very similar to what i ended up doing which is this:
Libro(const std::string = "", const std::string = "", const std::string = "", int = 0, int = 0, const std::string = "", int = 0, const maximos & = maximos());
